# Ghostscript text is not selectable on pages with images

Tags: pdftex, ghostscript, pdf-a

After normal compiling, I am processing a PDF file with the following `ghostscript` command in order to produce a (hopefully) PDF/A compliant file.

```
gs -dPDFA
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite
   -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1
   -dPrinted=false
   -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer
   -dSAFER
   -dNOPAUSE
   -dQUIET
   -dBATCH
   -dNOOUTERSAVE 
   -sColorConversionStrategy=UseDeviceIndependentColor
   -sProcessColorModel=DeviceRGB
   -sOutputFile=thesis.pdf
   main.pdf pdfmarks
```

This mostly works (I have a working outline in my PDF viewer and hyperlinks also work now), except for one thing. The text is selectable and copyable on almost all pages, except for pages which contain images. It does not matter if the image is another PDF or a PNG. Tikz pictures and MetaFont images are fine, though.

I tried a different `PDFSETTINGS`, `/prepress` and in an earlier iteration of this command also without `-dSAFER` and `-dPrinted=false`.

The original PDF file is compiled with `pdflatex`, if it makes any difference.

This question is quite difficult to research, since almost all ghostscript documentation contains the words "text" and "image".

Answer (score 1):

I would put my effort in directly creating a PDF/A compliant pdf with `pdflatex` or `lualatex` in the first place. This will give you a valid PDF/A directly:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdfa]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}[2020/03/01]

\author{me,him}
\title{How to create a PDF/A-1b document}

\immediate\pdfobj stream attr{/N 3} file{sRGB.icc}
\pdfcatalog{%
  /OutputIntents [ <<
    /Type /OutputIntent
    /S /GTS_PDFA1
      /DestOutputProfile \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R
    /OutputConditionIdentifier (sRGB IEC61966-2.1)
    /Info(sRGB IEC61966-2.1)
  >> ]
}

\begin{document}

lorem ipsum \url{http://stackexchange.com/}

\end{document}
```

This example validates in Acrobat DC *and* verapdf 1.14.8 both when compiled with LuaLaTeX and pdfLaTeX with up to date packages.
[image: Preflight validation result]
It looks like Graipher's font setup is dodgy.

If you want to include images later I recommend including pdf that already validate pdf/a. Jpg images with embedded colour profiles can work but some validators request the embedded images metadata to be PDF/A compliant. This is hard to achieve without Acrobat Pro. You would run into that problem also with Ghostscript. PNG do not work because they don't provide embedded colour profiles.

Comment: I downloaded the colour profile from [here](http://www.color.org/srgbprofiles.xalter#v2) and tried compiling it afterwards. It complains that `keeppdfinfo` is not a valid option for `hypersetup`.

Comment: Without that option it seems to work and produce a PDF/A file, but now the hyperlinks no longer work. Apart from a load of additional packages being loaded, I currently first load `hyperxmp` and then `hyperref`, does that make a difference?

Comment: And the produced file fails compliance using `verapdf` with [many failures](https://gist.github.com/graipher/49d125dcf0f12dec953a940e29961497).

Comment: keeppdfinfo and hyperlinks: update your package `hyperxmp` to at least 5.0. Verapdf failures: They come from embedded graphics. Convert them to PDF/A-1b before including them in LaTeX. Flatten Transparency in embedded graphics or use a newer standard such as PDF/A-2b.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which I got fixed by changing to `-dCompatibilityLevel=1.4`  from `-dCompatibilityLevel=1.3`.

No idea on the why, though.